# open pdf link with python selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriverwait

```
os.environ['PATH'] += 
   r"C:\Users\dew23\OneDrive\Computer Science"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())

driver.get("https://official.nba.com/nba-injury- 
report-2022-23-season/")
WebDriverWait(driver, 
   10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, 
   '//*[@id="main"]/div/section[1]/div/div/p/a[12]')))
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="main"]/div/section[1]/div/div/p/a[12]').send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
```

the link gets clicked but it does not open the pdf file. how do I open the file in a new tab?

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues here:

1. The main issue causing your code to click the element but not to open the file is because you need to wait for element clickability. Element presence is a very first state when element is already presented but still not fully rendered. So, clicking a web element on that stage will just do nothing as you see yourself.
2. No need to get the element again with `driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="main"]/div/section[1]/div/div/p/a[12]')` after you already applied `WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="main"]/div/section[1]/div/div/p/a[12]')))` since the former method returns a web element object.
3. Long `'//*[@id="main"]/div/section[1]/div/div/p/a[12]'` XPath expression can be changed by this XPath `"//a[contains(@href,'2022-11-22_11AM')]"` it is much more precise and reliable.

So, the final code can be like this:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

options = Options()
options.add_argument("start-maximized")
options.add_argument('--disable-notifications')

webdriver_service = Service('C:\webdrivers\chromedriver.exe')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, service=webdriver_service)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)

url = "https://official.nba.com/nba-injury-report-2022-23-season/"
driver.get(url)

wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[contains(@href,'2022-11-22_11AM')]"))).click()
```

And it woks, the result is

[image]

Comment: thank you for your thorough explanation. when I run the final code you offered, I get the same result. the pdf does not open. any other suggestions? the code I am running is the exact same as yours

Comment: I run it on my PC several times and it worked just fine.

Comment: I am using VScode. would that be causing a problem?

Comment: I don't know...

Comment: that's alright, thank you for your help